# How to divide a json into several parts in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, divide

I was designing a waterfall page, and these days I'm getting started on Angularjs. I wanna divide the json data into several parts to display wrap the each in a  different DIV. The whole data is in array, called items.
`<div id="dym-waterfall">`
`<div class="dym" ng-repeat="item in items"> </div>`
`<div class="dym" ng-repeat="item in items"> </div>`
`<div class="dym" ng-repeat="item in items"> </div>`
`<div class="dym" ng-repeat="item in items"> </div>`
`</div>`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways of solving your problem.

Firstly, you could assign a scope value to every part in "items".
For instance, assume this is your JSON array:

```
[data1, data2, data3, data4, data5]
```

And in your controller do this:

```
$scope.data1 = items[0];
```

Do this for every part you need broken up. Keep in mind that the 'data1' part is arbitrary and that you can make up any name you want.
Then in your html:

```
<div class="dym" ng-repeat="stuff in data1"></div>
```

Alternatively, you could have your html like this:

```
<div class="dym" ng-repeat="item in items[0]></div>
```

The first method is better if you also have to do some additional processing, and the other is good if the data structure is ready to go already.